# TCheckBox.Data invalid typecast when using as TValue

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rtti, tvalue

Steps to reproduce:

-new firemonkey-application

-add TCheckBox to form

Now create a method with following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Foo;
var a,b:Integer; lVal:TValue;
begin
  lVal:=TValue.From<Integer>(42);
  a:=lVal.AsInteger;
  checkbox1.Data:=TValue.From<Integer>(42);
  b:=checkbox1.Data.AsInteger;
end;
```

The cast with lVal runs without problems, checkbox1.data however, even if it's a TValue too, throws an "EInvalidCast"-Error, when calling `AsInteger`. The same error appears when using `checkbox1.data.AsType<Integer>` instead.

Am I misusing `TCheckBox.Data` here or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TCheckBox.Data` contains `boolean` value, specifically check box checked state. That is why you get `EInvalidCast` error when you try to read `Integer` from it.

The reason why you seemingly can put `Integer` data in, is because `TCheckBox.SetData` will just ignore invalid data types and sets `Data` to `False`.